# How to show a modal confirmation message before leaving (closing or losing focus) of a window?

Tags: c++, qt, window, desktop

I want to show confirmation messagebox and block the screen before user leaves (alt + tab (close or loose focus)) MainWindow. How to do this?

**here is my code**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QMainWindow::showFullScreen();
    this->installEventFilter(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){
    if(event->type() == 128){
        QMessageBox::information(this, "title", "text", QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Cancel);

        return true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: If the user "leaves" your window, your window looses *focus*, there are events for that. However, nagging the user because of that is not what I would consider good UI design, and will irritate the user (I know it would irritate me) quite a lot.

Comment: Also, a window loosing focus is something completely different from a window being closed. You might want to update your headline into something more appropriate.

Comment: I want to block screen before he clicks "ok" or "cancel" button. It is important for my application. this is not usual application. i have web view in it and if user want to open different program(clicks ok) i have to send request to the server(call restful web service)

Comment: it's totally not clear what do you mean under "block screen"

Comment: **I'm not your user yet, but I hate your product already**. This is a usability nightmare. Don't even think of doing any kind of modal (blocking) interaction when a window loses focus! It's a tragically bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For close event:

Reimplement `closeEvent` method in your MainWindow class. [Link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent)

For window activation and deactivation events try [following](https://gist.github.com/01walid/2276009):

```
bool MainWindow::event(QEvent * e) // overloading event(QEvent*) method of QMainWindow 
{
    switch(e->type())
    {
        // ...

        case QEvent::WindowActivate :
            // gained focus
            break ;

        case QEvent::WindowDeactivate :
            // lost focus
            break ;
        // ...
    } ;
    return QMainWindow::event(e) ;
}
```

Comment: this variant works like my previous variant. Still I can't block screen on alt+tab before user clicks "ok" or "cancel". MessageBox stays  background.

Comment: it looks like you should describe what you want to achieve in more understandable way... to "activate" window you can try to call method activateWindow() http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#activateWindow or raise()

Comment: but as I wrote it's not clear what behavior you want finally to achieve

Comment: Thank you for your response. i found this function setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint). I want to hold main window always on focus while users moves on another program